# How to convert date from MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert date from MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY, how i can do this using SimpleDateFormat in Java? (Note: DD can be start date of that month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    try {
        String str_date = "01/11";
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        System.out.println("Today is " + formatter.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
    }
```

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - He can replace to the pattern he wants.

Comment: My approach:                                                  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
java.util.Date today = DateUtils.parseDate("01/2011","MM/yyyy");
formattedDate = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println("Formatted Date : " + formattedDate);

Answer (score 5):

please go through the http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html following link for more clarity.

One way of implementation i have in my mind is :

```
String yourDate = <yourDate>
DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date= new Date();
date = (Date)dateFormat.parse(yourDate);
//String dateString= dateFormat.format(date);
/*Print your date*/
```

Please go through this link [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: The pattern `MM/DD/YYYY` will most probably not do what you intend.

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY would return you IllegalArgumentException for pattern 'Y'

Comment: your solution will return IllegalArgumentException for "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is using string manipulation.

```
String date1 = "12/2010";
String date2 = date1.replace("/","/01/");
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.parse( 
    "12/2016" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" ) )
)
.atDay( 1 )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) )  // 12/01/2016
```

## java.time

Java now includes the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to represent exactly this kind of value, a month and a year without a day-of-month.

The default format for parsing/generating strings of a month-year is `YYYY-MM`. That format is defined as part of the ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default.

Your input string has alternate format so we must specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "12/2016" ;  // December 2016.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" );
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( input , f );
```

See the results by calling `toString`.

```
String output = ym.toString();
```

> 2016-12

Specify a day-of-month to create a `LocalDate` instance. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = ym.atDay( 1 );
```

You can let the class figure out the last day of the month. Remember that February varies in length for Leap Year. The `YearMonth` class knows how to handle Leap Year.

```
LocalDate ld = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

FYI, Java has a similar class, [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).